# How to convert string with point to symbol

Tags: ruby, symbols, literals

I am trying to convert the string `"country."` to a symbol. I expect to receive `:country.` including the point `.`.

I tried the following, but they do not work as my symbols still have quotes.

```
"country.".to_sym; #=> :"country."
"country.".intern; #=> :"country."
"country.".parameterize.underscore.to_sym; #=> :country
"country\.".to_sym; #=> :"country."
```

Comment: it's converted to :country. for you? (included the point as part of the simbol)

Comment: Yes, it is working. Even your own code shows it working, at least in lines 1, 2 and 4, the period is clearly there.

Comment: All good...: `"country.".to_sym.class #=> Symbol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working as expected. 
A symbol most of the time looks like:

```
:symbol_name
```

However when the symbol contains special characters such as spaces or hyphens, or in your case a period, it needs to be enclosed in quotes:

```
:"symbol name with-many special characters."
```

Although it doesn't look 'correct', it will act as any other symbol.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it will help you:

```
:'country.'
```